# Limit length of an html paragraph dynamically using php

Tags: php, html

I want to set the limit of the content coming from database dynamically in php. That is, I need to set the data to a paragraph, but I need to trim the input from the database before assigning it to the html paragraph.  I tried using `substr`. But couldn't succeed. How to achieve this?

The code I have done so far is given below.

```
<?php
foreach($conn->query("SELECT * FROM product_page ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10") as $st) {


echo'
<div class="col-md-4" style=" margin-bottom:50px;">
<div class="grid_7">
<div class="element">
<div class="grid">
                    <figure class="effect-apollo">
                        <img src="admin/'.$st['product_image'].'" alt="" />
                    <figcaption>
                            <h2></h2>
                            <p></p>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
</div>

<h4>'.$st['product_name'].'</h4>
<p style="text-align:justify; ">'.$st['product_content'].'</p>
</div><!--end element-->
<div style="margin-left:20px;">
<a href="RFID.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" ><div class="button"><i class="fa fa-download" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; background: none; margin: 0px 30px; float:none;"></i>Download Pdf</div></a>
</div><!--end -->
</div>
</div><!-- end col-md-4-->';

}
?>
```

Comment: *"I tried using substr but error is coming not getting the logic how to code. "* Can you elaborate on that part? What errors did you get? What is the current outcome and what would you like it to be? And where is this call to substr in the first place?

Comment: actually i m not getting what to write exactly here <p style="text-align:justify; ">'.$st['product_content'].'</p> using substr can you plz wrte the code for limit in these line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the limit length is in `$len`, then
Add this line at the starting of your `foreach` block.

`$para = substr ( $st['product_content'] , 0 , $len );`

(Reference of [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php))

Now replace

`<p style="text-align:justify; ">'.$st['product_content'].'</p>`

line with

`<p style="text-align:justify; ">'.$para.'</p>`

#### Fully modified code

```
<?php
$len = 50; //assuming the length is 50
foreach($conn->query("SELECT * FROM product_page ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10") as $st) {
$para = substr ( $st['product_content'] , 0 , $len );

echo'
<div class="col-md-4" style=" margin-bottom:50px;">
<div class="grid_7">
<div class="element">
<div class="grid">
                    <figure class="effect-apollo">
                        <img src="admin/'.$st['product_image'].'" alt="" />
                    <figcaption>
                            <h2></h2>
                            <p></p>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
</div>

<h4>'.$st['product_name'].'</h4>
<p style="text-align:justify; ">'.$para .'</p>
</div><!--end element-->
<div style="margin-left:20px;">
<a href="RFID.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" ><div class="button"><i class="fa fa-download" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; background: none; margin: 0px 30px; float:none;"></i>Download Pdf</div></a>
</div><!--end -->
</div>
</div><!-- end col-md-4-->';

}
?>
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer by ticking on it and up voting if it solved your issue.